# Dart Aqueduct server basic authorization

Tags: dart, authorization, aqueduct

I'm learning about how authentication works using the Aqueduct framework.

In my channel.dart file I have a route:

```
router
  .route('/protected') 
  .link(() => Authorizer.basic(validator))
  .link(() => ProtectedController());
```

But I don't know how to create the `validator`. In the [docs](https://aqueduct.io/docs/auth/authorizer/#using-authorizers-without-authserver) I see that I can make a custom Authorizer without using an AuthServer. The code example is this:

```
class BasicValidator implements AuthValidator {
  @override
  FutureOr<Authorization> validate<T>(AuthorizationParser<T> parser, T authorizationData, {List<AuthScope> requiredScope}) {}
    var user = await userForName(usernameAndPassword.username);
    if (user.password == hash(usernameAndPassword.password, user.salt)) {
      return Authorization(...);
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

I'd like to make a basic working example, but this is the closest that I could get:

```
class BasicValidator implements AuthValidator {
  @override
  FutureOr<Authorization> validate<T>(AuthorizationParser<T> parser, T authorizationData, {List<AuthScope> requiredScope}) {

    final validUsername = 'bob';
    final validPassword = 'password123';

    // How do I get the parsed username?
    // How do I get the parsed password?

    if (parsedUsername == validUsername && parsedPassword == validPassword) {
      // How do I create an Authorization?
      return Authorization(...);
    }

    return null;
  }

  // What is this?
  @override
  List<APISecurityRequirement> documentRequirementsForAuthorizer(APIDocumentContext context, Authorizer authorizer, {List<AuthScope> scopes}) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Could anyone show me a basic working example of Basic authorization validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authorizationData` is an instance of `AuthBasicCredentials` when using `Authorizer.basic`. An object of this type has `username` and `password` fields derived from parsing the 'Authorization' header from a request.

An `Authorization` *object* is a container for data related to the authorized resource owner (such as their user ID). It is used by subsequent controllers to control authorization without having to look up the authorized user again; you should populate it with any authorization information you have available.

`documentRequirementsForAuthorizer` is used during OpenAPI document generation. An `Authorizer` that uses your validator will encode the returned security requirements into the OpenAPI operations being secured.

See also http://aqueduct.io/docs/auth/authorizer/#using-authorizers-without-authserver.

```
@override
FutureOr<Authorization> validate<T>(AuthorizationParser<T> parser, T authorizationData, {List<AuthScope> requiredScope}) {

    final validUsername = 'bob';
    final validPassword = 'password123';

    final credentials = authorizationData as AuthBasicCredentials;

    if (credentials.username == validUsername 
    && credentials.password == validPassword) {

      return Authorization(
       null, // no client ID for basic auth 
       await getUserIDFromUsername(validUsername), // This is your problem to solve
       this, // always this
       credentials: credentials // if you want to pass this info along 
       );
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Comment: If I'm not using OpenAPI documentation (yet), is `null` the most secure default return value for `documentRequirementsForAuthorizer`?

Comment: Also, the docs example shows a `hash()` function. Is that in some library or do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: Regarding my second question, I see there is a `AuthUtility.generatePasswordHash()` function.